# Unused variable "mystring" warning in iOS

Tags: objective-c, global-variables

I am taking a Constants.h file for saving all my values. And i declare like this :

```
static NSString *NAME = @"Name";
static NSString *MAILID = @"Mail-id";
static NSString *ADDRESS = @"Address";
```

I also use this key in my code. But always its showing a warning **Unused variable "NAME"**

If i take

```
const NSString *NAME = @"Name";
```

Then its showing Error. So please anybody can help me, how can i resolve this warning ?

Thanks :)

Comment: You're aware of the difference between `const` and `static`? What is the second error?

Comment: Delete the app from simulator or device and clean the project and run again

Comment: @dheeru There is no need to delete anything. A clean build is good, but this isn't an issue solved by deleting builds.

Comment: @rmaddy: U r right. No need to delete . I am already did this procedure but no changes

Comment: @Tommy: Error is: ld: 219 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Why you are not using #define to defined these strings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, and therefore in Objective-C, a `static` is a variable with file-level scope. Both `#import` and `#include` have the same effect as copying and pasting the header file's text into your source file. So with `static`, each file that includes the header is getting its own personal copy of the symbols `NAME`, `MAILID`, etc. If you don't use one the compiler will therefore warn you.

`const` means constant. If used before the asterisk then it means a constant `NSString`, which doesn't have a lot of semantic sense because `NSString` is an opaque type. If you just use `const` you're also having every file that includes the header redeclare the variables. So you'll get a liker error.

What you probably want in the header is:

```
extern NSString *const NAME;
```

That says: (i) `estern` — not here, but in another unit; and (ii) `NSString *const` — it is a pointer to `NSString` and the address within the pointer never changes.

Then in any single implementation file add:

```
NSString *const NAME = @"NAME";
```

As otherwise every single compilation unit will sit back and expect one of the others to define it. You'll therefore get a linker error that the symbol is undefined.

Comment: Now its showing this error : ld: 219 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I am using NSString *const NAME = @"NAME";

Comment: @SRNayak You need `extern` in the .h declaration to avoid all of the duplicate errors, just as shown in this answer.

Comment: @rmaddy: I am using only 1 Constants.h file

Comment: @SRNayak I get that. But you need to have it as `extern NSString *const NAME;` in the .h file. Without the `extern` you get all the errors you see.

Comment: Actually rmaddy i am not getting u properly which .h file u told. Please can u share what u want to say. i think i can understand. please